# p overflowing out of div

Tags: html, css, overflow

*Dear community*

I recently wanted to create a div with an image, a title and text.
As shown in the image, the image should be aligned left and on the right side the title followed by a text.

But, **the text overflows the parent div**. How can the p element set to the exact max-height, so that the element "ends" when "touching" the parent div? Like that, I want to set `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, which stops the text from overflowing - ellipsis is important, that the text does not abruptly stop so that it creates the 3 dots at the end.

In the screenshot, you can see the **dotted line**, which indicates my intention (with a bit of margin of the p at the bottom to div). The **blue box** is the size of the p element (from the Google Chrome element inspector).

[image: screenshot of the problem]

```css
div {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 35em;
      height: 10em;
    }
    
    img {
      float: left;
      width: 40%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-right: 1em;
    }
    
    p {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-right: 2em;
    }
```

```html
<div>
      <img src="IMAGE SOURCE">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
```

*Thank you all for your help. If you have any improvements in the question, feel free to edit it to make it clearer to the public.*

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate `<div></div>` for your content and set `overflow-y` to `scroll`. If you don't want the text to be visible at all, set `overflow-y` to `hidden`. Here's how you do it:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 35em;
    height: 10em;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

img {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/280000/nahled/gradient-black-blue-background-1542385776MaH.jpg">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've changed this, but how can I add the text-overflow: ellipsis; to the text? Because now, the overflow is "stopped" at the div.content.